# Having trouble identifing this connector

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to find a male component that will fit the female component described and pictured below. Unfortunately I do not have the male end to provide pictures of. Any help identifying this connector or any tips for identifying connectors are much appreciated.

```
40-pin
20.3mm long
3.2mm wide
```

[image: unknown pcb conector]

Comment: Looks like a generic 1mm pitch rectangular connector, similar to this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/SFM210-LPSE-D05-SP-BK/S9268-ND/2039572

Comment: Is the black insulation raised off of the board? By how much?

Comment: Its about 1.5-2mm high off the board.

Answer (score 2):

As @EugeneSh. said, it is most likely a standard 20x2 rectangular 1mm pitch connector.

The female part could be compatible with these:

[SAM9228-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/samtec-inc/CLM-120-02-F-D/SAM9228-ND/6677965)

And the male part could be compatible with these:

[455-1868-1-ND](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/SM40B-SRDS-G-TF(LF)(SN)/455-1868-1-ND/926894)

Although it's difficult to tell from your picture whether that's raised enough to accept the shroud on the linked part.